# SQL Server efficiently filter and sort Properties table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a scenario that we need to filter and sort documents stored in the documents table by document properties. **Each document can have an unknown number of Properties.**

The Documents table columns are something like:
ID, Name, Modified, ...

and the Properties table is:
DocumentID, PropertyName, TextValue, DateValue

All columns in the Properties table are indexed to allow fast retrieval.

The first attempt was to write a query that looks like:

```
SELECT DocumentID 
From Properties 
WHERE (PropertyName ='Status' and TextValue = ' Approved')
```

This worked fine for simple filter scenario. For a scenario that returns

```
SELECT DocumentID 
From Properties 
WHERE ((PropertyName ='Status' and TextValue = ' Approved') and   
       (PropertyName ='Dept' and TextValue = 'IT'))
```

Once there are more filter conditions nothing is returned.

After some research I tried a few options:

- Using PIVOT to convert rows to columns with dynamic sql. Very slow and still does not work. Documents can have unique properties
- Using Dynamic with left join
- Using subqueries

I have followed the answer provided [Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server).

With mongodb that would be a much easier task but we need to achieve this same flexibility and speed with SQL Server.

SQL PIVOT is way too slow for this scenario. Any suggestion to how can this be made fast?

Update: After reading some of the suggestions and comments I have have tweaked the proposals to the following:

```
SELECT DocumentID FROM Properties
WHERE DocumentID in
    ( SELECT DocumentID  FROM Properties WHERE Name = 'Status' and TextValue = 'Approved')
    and | or DocumentID in( SELECT DocumentID  FROM Properties WHERE Name = 'Dept' and TextValue = 'IT')
```

Next step is to test performance to large data sets > 5million 
Any suggestions for the above pseudo code?

Comment: You would want to use OR between the conditions. There are no rows that can have a value of Status AND Dept.

Comment: A property/value table is *inefficient* by definition. Even with indexing queries will be inefficient as dates, numbers and names get all mixed up. Never mind the lack of type safety or the wasted space as you have to store everything as text. MongoDB doesn't store anything as property/value pairs either, it stores them as *objects* with specific properties. If you want to store different types of data, use multiple tables, not a catch-all table.

Comment: From this [quite relevant answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93124/eav-is-it-really-bad-in-all-scenarios) `EAV gives you enough rope to hang yourself and in this industry, things should be designed to the lowest level of complexity because the guy replacing you on the project will likely be an idiot.`

Comment: One the funniest and realistic stories about EAV gone awry ever. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PropertyName` can never have a value of both 'Status' and' Approved'.

`TextValue` can never have a value of both ' and 'IT'.

`and` is processed before `or` but `( )` before either, so you could skip the `( )` but typically leave it for clarity.

```
SELECT DocumentID 
From Properties 
WHERE (PropertyName ='Status' and TextValue = ' Approved') 
   or (PropertyName ='Dept'   and TextValue = 'IT')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use OR between your compound conditions or you will never find anything.

Here is an example.

```
SELECT DocumentID 
From Properties 
WHERE ((PropertyName ='Status' and TextValue = ' Approved') OR   
       (PropertyName ='Dept' and TextValue = 'IT'))
```

Comment: this would be a solution except the front end allows for defining conditions like show docs where (Status = Approved and | or Dept = 'IT'). How do you suggest this gets handled?

Comment: I couldn't possibly answer that as I have no idea what your application is or how you are trying to allow searching.

Comment: A CMS. Any created doc can have its own set of properties mostly short strings. This apps then allows for users to create queries / views with a combination of one or more conditions separated by or / and